# Microsoft Teams Embedded 'Share' button won't pick up current page URL to share -

Tags: javascript, html, share

I've been trying to get the 'Share to Microsoft Teams' embedded button to pick up the page it's inserted in's URL to share it directly to MS Teams.

Here are the ressources:

```html
<script async defer src="https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js"></script>
<div
  class="teams-share-button"
  data-href="https://<link-to-be-shared>">
</div>
```

[Click here to access the JS provided by microsoft](https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js)

Does anyone have any idea how I could get it to work by tweaking a few things ?
I've attempted to pick up the current URL and have href replaced by it but did not manage :(.

Thank you so much SO community :)
kind regards,
d

Answer (score 0):

I managed by modifying the values pulled by data-href in the js provided
the href is defined as self and if defined as window.location.href
data-href becomes current html location :D
thank you to anyone who looked
have a nice day